# MVC jQuery POST fails to update the cart information in the second request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am just trying to update the cart using jQuery POST. It's success with the first request. However, it's seem to throw a 500 server error within the second request. The problem is after I debug it. The Action Result at the second time it's try to render the view instead of sending the JSON object to the callback function. Here is my code bellow. 
Here is my Action Result inside my cart

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateResultCart(int productId)
    {
        // Retrieve the album from the database
        var addedProduct = _db.Products
            .Single(pr => pr.ProductID == productId);

        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCartModel.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Set up our ViewModel
        var shoppingCartData = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
        };
        return Json(shoppingCartData);
    }
```

Here is my JavaScript function

```
$(function () {   
$("#AddCartProduct").click(function () {
    var productId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    if (productId != '') {
        // Perform the ajax post
        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
        var jqxhr = $.post("/Cart/UpdateResultCart", { "productId": productId },   function(data) {
            alert("success");
            $('#cart-item').text(": " + data.CartItems.length + " Items");
            $('#total-price').text("Total Price:" + numberToCurrency(data.CartTotal));                
        })
        .done(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .fail(function() { alert("error"); });   
    }
});
});
```

Finally,Here is my HTML Element in the partial view that needs to be updated

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {           
<ul>
    <li>             
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </li>
    |
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    |
    <li>
        <a href="#">Cart</a>
        <label class="cart-item">: 0 Items</label>|
        <label class="total-price">$0.00</label>
    </li>               

</ul>    
} else {
<ul>
    @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>*@
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>|
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>|
    <li>
        <a href="#">Cart</a>
        <label class="cart-item">: 0 Items</label>|
        <label class="total-price">$0.00</label>
    </li>               
</ul>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: put a breakpoint at the begining of `UpdateResultCart`. check if productId comes in as `0`. That would explain the `500`.

Comment: I tried that, It's always got the product Id and it's not null or 0

Comment: step thru the remaining steps. start with *addedProduct*. see if it comes back populated or raises exception on single(). then step thru your cart methods. walk it all the way till the return.

Comment: I tried that, The first thing was going in all the steps correctly and returning the JSON object to the JavaScript callback function and it's update the cart items. Then once I click add cart again it's fire the click event again and send the POST request to the Action Result, then it's get the correct result from the UpdateResultCart. However, it's did not go back to the callback function instead it's back to the product then to the category that they are a partial view as well then to the error view with [A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type ]

Comment: wow. unfathomable. will think over this...